# Evaluating infinite integrals with poles of second order.

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve this type of integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{zt}}{(z^2-1)^2}dz.$$

I know that if the function in the integral has simple poles on the real axis then you can apply this formula:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Q(z)dz=2 \pi j \sum Rez^+ +\pi j \sum Rez^0.$$

However, the function under my integral has poles of second order.

$z=1 ; z=-1$

What is the approach in this case? And how would different values for $t$ change the result?

Comment: When you wrote $j$ did you mean the imaginary number i.e. $j = \sqrt{-1}$? And when you wrote $Re$ did you mean $\text{Res}$ i.e. the residue?

Answer (score 1):

For the Residue Theorem, the residue at $z_0$, which is a $m$-order singularity of $f(z)$, is:

$\frac{1}{\left(m-1\right)!} \lim_{z \to z_{0}} \frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}} \{{\left(z-z_0\right)}^mf(z)\}$

Note: Alpha says this integral diverges.

Comment: But does the formula for the integral still works for a m-order pole?

Comment: I believe it does.  My understanding is that poles are a type of singularity.

Comment: What about the values of t? How does it change the result?

Comment: $f(z)$ is the integrand, so when you evaluate the residue it depends on t.